Coupling of mechanical and electrical resonances in piezoceramics
What is the relationship between electrical and mechanical resonance of piezoceramics.
I have a piezoceramic disk made of PZT-5A material. Feeding a sinusoidal waveform to it from a signal generator, I found that its lowest impedance is reached at a frequency approximately equal to 190 kHz, as I understand this is its resonance frequency.
After that, I decided to test it using the formula, fr=Nt/h. Nt-velocity of sound in piezoceramics. h-thickness of the disk (this formula is given on americanpiezo site). By substituting my values (Nt =2000m/s, h=6mm) I got that the resonance frequency is 333 kHz.
Do I understand correctly that a sinusoidal signal with a frequency of 190 kHz makes the piezoceramic disk oscillate with a frequency of 333 kHz?

Please link the data sheet for the actual device.

As the "speaker", we can use it at a frequency higher than the resonance frequency ...
http://olivier.granier.free.fr/MOOC-Francais/Induction-EM/co/Haut-parleur.html https://engineering.purdue.edu/ece103/LectureNotes/SRS_Loudspeaker_Parameters.pdf

Drive at 190, the motion is at 190. Barring nonlinear effects that is.
Usually the lowest resonance for disks is the radial mode, which depends on the diameter not thickness. Disks (and other shapes) have multiple resonanceS. Also velocity is anisotropic and changes some with applied stress or bias.
